# Typed heterogenous object insert, preventing old keys from being overwritten statically

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-level-computation

I'd like to add a new field to heterogeneous object, knowing at *compile* time that the key is not present (or at least not present in the type of the object). The purpose of this is to keep track of initialised resources and their types st you can't access an uninitialised resource in a typesafe way, and you know all initialised resources statically.

Ideally, the function would look like this:

```
type FreshKey<A,K> = K extends keyof A ? never : K

const f <A, K extends string, v> =  (x: A) 
                                 => (k: FreshKey<A,K>, v: V)
                                 => A & { [k: K]: V} = ...
```

With usage being something like this:

```
const z = {}
const y = f(z)("foo", []);
const x = f(y)("bar", 3);
const v = f(x)("baz", "");

const v2 = f(x)("foo", []) // shouldn't typecheck because "foo" is already present
```

The problem is that I can't even describe the resulting type of f in a way that typescript is happy with. I hit typescript[1337] (An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type of generic type...).

The ideal implementation would typecheck too, but I'd be happy to just cast it

Comment: How are you wanting to add new Keys? One by one? Or are you looking to "merge" objects?

Comment: The K type parameter describes the new key, so the new keys are the (first arg to the) second parameter to f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a generic type to ensure our provided key is unqiue

```
type EnsureFreshKey<OBJECT extends object, KEY extends string | number | symbol> = KEY extends keyof OBJECT ? never : KEY;
```

Create a function to handle adding the new key

```
function AddNewKey<OBJECT extends object>(a: OBJECT) {
  return <NEW_KEY extends string | number | symbol, VALUE>(key: EnsureFreshKey<OBJECT, NEW_KEY>, value: VALUE) => {
    // Check for KEY uniqueness at runtime
    if (key in a && a[key as unknown as keyof OBJECT] !== undefined) {
      throw new Error(`Key "${String(key)}" already exists in object ${JSON.stringify(a)}`)
    }
    
    // You can decide whether to create a new object or just assign
    // the key onto the existing object
    return {
      ...a,
      [key]: value
    } as OBJECT & { [key in NEW_KEY]: VALUE }
  }
}
```

Note:

This piece of code will result in `never` if `NEW_KEY` already exists in `OBJECT`.
And your variable, `NEW_KEY` should never be of type `never`

```
key: EnsureFreshKey<A, FK>
```

Test Cases

```
const a = {}
const b = AddNewKey(z)("foo", []);
const c = AddNewKey(y)("bar", 3);
const d = AddNewKey(x)("baz", "");
const e = AddNewKey(x)("foo", []); // correctly throws an error
```

Comment: That was significantly simpler that I expected. I hadn't anticipated that a strongly typed heterogenous thing would extend object (though obviously it does...), and that lets you just return `Object & ...`